# The view doesn't display products

Tags: views, commerce, taxonomy-terms, 9

I've edited the default product type and added a taxonomy term reference field and added some products that reference my product categories.

The default taxonomy view isn't display my products, I believe because it just shows related nodes?!

How do I get the taxonomy view to display related products?

Comment: Several possible solutions are suggested here: [Taxonomy Terms Not Displaying Products](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce/issues/2988132). Basically modules [TVI](https://www.drupal.org/project/tvi) or [Drupal 8 Commerce product taxonomy filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_product_taxonomy_filter) or recreate Taxonomy term Views for Products manually.

Answer (score 1):

Views are designed by default to query a single base table. You'll need to create your own product catalog View instead of trying to use the default one provided for listing content.